# Cloud Pub/Sub: Pull subscriber with GAE/Go Standard

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-pubsub

Can I create Cloud Pub/Sub pull subscriber with GAE/Go Standard Environment?

I read [this page](https://cloud.google.com/go/getting-started/using-pub-sub), but this is GAE Flexible environment.
I would like to create pull subscriber with GAE/Go Standard.

Can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

No, You can't do that. The proper way to use PubSub with GAE Standard is to create a push subscription which delivers each message to an App Engine endpoint you have defined.